# Flattening an array in a JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object which I want to flatten before exporting it to CSV. I'd like to use the flatten_json module for this.

My JSON input looks like this:

```
{
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "responseDetails": {
        "total": 5754
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1324651
        },
        {
            "id": 5686131
        },
        {
            "id": 2165735
        },
        {
            "id": 2133256
        }
    ]
}
```

Easy so far even for a beginner like me, but what I'm interesting in exporting is only the data array. So, I would think of this:

```
data_json = json["data"]
flat_json = flatten_json.flatten(data_json)
```

Which doesn't work, since data is an array, stored as a list in Python, not as a dictionary:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1324651
    },
    {
        "id": 5686131
    },
    {
        "id": 2165735
    },
    {
        "id": 2133256
    }
]
```

How should I proceed to feed the content of the data array into the flatten_json function?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: Try to validate your json, you have to remove the `,` in total record.

Comment: Indeed, but that's just the effect of manually cleaning my JSON example. In my real-life, much longer record, the JSON is valid and computer-generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function expects a ditionary, let's pass one:

```
flat_json = flatten_json.flatten({'data': data_json})
```

Output:

```
{'data_0_id': 1324651, 'data_1_id': 5686131, 'data_2_id': 2165735, 'data_3_id': 2133256}
```

Comment: Duh! I'm really a beginner. I mean, this is my first Python program, so I still miss the obvious! :-D Thanks!!!!

Comment: Not a big deal, Happy Pythoning :)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the keys you want to ignore when you call the flatten method. For example, in your case, you can do the following.

```
flatten_json.flatten(dic, root_keys_to_ignore={'responseStatus', 'responseDetails'})
```

where `dic` is the original JSON input.

This will give as output:

```
{'data_0_id': 1324651, 'data_1_id': 5686131, 'data_2_id': 2165735, 'data_3_id': 2133256}
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)